# How do I transfer a local video file between two html pages

Tags: javascript, html, web, local-files

I am making a website that will access and then display my locally stored movies. I have several pages, but there are only two that are important for this. **I want to be able to get permission on the first page and then play the movie on the second page.** Let's just play the first movie on the list to make things more simple.

**The problem is that I can not access the local files once I change pages.**

Here is my code, I might have some little errors in this code, but I can fix those.

// is a comment

> **page1.html**

```
<script src = "page1.js"></script>

<body>
  // ask user to select movies
  <label for = "movies">Select your movies:</label>
  <input type = "file" id = "movies" multiple/><br>

  // stores movies and changes location to page 2
  <button id = "start" onclick = "loadMovies()">Load movies and play first one</button>
</body>
```

> **page1.js**

```
function loadMovies() {
  // store movies from input in localMovies
  const selectedItems = document.getElementById("movies");
  const localMovies = selectedItems.files;
  
  // change location to second page
  location.href = "page2.html";
}
```

> **page2.html**

```
<script src = "page2.js"></script>

<body onload = "startMovie()>
  <video id = "video" controls><video>
</body>
```

> **page2.js**

```
function startMovie() {
  // make and then set a URL for the first movie in the list
  movieURL = url.createObjectURL(localMovies[0]);
  videoTag = document.getElementById("video");
  videoTag.src = movieURL
```

I don't know how to transfer `localMovies` or somehow accessing it from page2. I don't think import/export or global variables will work because I don't write what `localMovies` is. It is created in the first javascript file, and so if you make it global, it will just end up being empty on the second page.

I need to be able to create a URL on page one for each movie and send that to page two without the URL scope dying.
Send the variable `localMovies` to page two without having to physically write what `localMovies` is.
Somehow give or transfer permission to access the local files to page two.
Or something else that would do something similar.